Read scanned data on a handheld Android barcode scanner
I am working on a custom ERP software that needs to run on a handheld android barcode scanner like this one. I need to be able to reliably read information that it is scanning.
After doing some research, I found solutions to reading input from a scanner which is plugged into a computer via USB, where it connects to the device via the HID profile, essentially acting as a keyboard. This is not what I am trying to do. I want to create an android app which operates on the actual device and reads the results of a scanning operation.
I'm sure this has been done before but I was unable to find any projects, so I would greatly appreciate any tips or links to other implementations. Thank you!

Wouldn't it be better to provide accurate information about the vendor and model in text rather than just writing a link to a product article? When I clicked on the link, some kind of confirmation screen appeared, so I gave up on looking any further. That type of product probably has a built-in hardware scanner, so surely the vendor provides an SDK for it? It seems normal to obtain such an SDK and use it to develop an application.

@kunif sorry for this link. Yes it is an android device with a built in hardware scanner. I have not purchased one yet, so this is just an example. How can I use the SDK to access the scanner information?

Please contact the support desk of the vendor of the equipment you want to use.
